how to use image lazyload on AMP blog using amp-script? I've tried it but the image still won't appear even though my amp is valid 100% full green
how to use image lazyload on AMP blog using amp-script? I've tried it but the image still won't appear even though my amp is valid 100% full green, do you have any suggestions for this problem? My goal is to get a green score on page speed when my blog appears on the amp version of the URL, thank you to those who are willing to answer.
<amp-script layout='container' script='amplazy'>  
<img data-src='https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/b/R29vZ2xl/AVvXsEidXZwZg2x00QtGfxfiYoAmTeRjJ2H1OaEsjwOwpPbU6hZG_n8EYEUN_6aGbNGTNKW7rTs5YoOZJF7bXS5_Z7hyVSXGNZXc-nEFgriUH0xSG6mysh4qI2lY95IyYxv4CqRqaOD2VLED8kuY/s1600/fold+%25281%2529.jpeg' height='394' src='data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=' width='700'/>
</amp-script>  
<script id='amplazy' target='amp-script' type='text/plain'>
function init() {
var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName(&#39;img&#39;);
for (var i=0; i&lt;imgDefer.length; i++) {
if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute(&#39;data-src&#39;)) {
imgDefer[i].setAttribute(&#39;src&#39;,imgDefer[i].getAttribute(&#39;data-src&#39;));
} } }
window.onload = init;
</script>

